# Search Filter method with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple code which should only return the row, which contains the word "Anne".

So when I type in "Anne" and click on the button, every row should be set to "display:none" except the row, which contains the word. But unfortunately it is not working. Can someone explain me why? I've tried to print out the results, but they are not working..

I've also tried to solve it with "this" because I've been taught, that in jQuery everything is saved in lists and it automatically iterates through the objects. Its this correct?

here the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Beginner</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        

        .d_show{
            display: "";
        }

        .d_none{
            display: none; 
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn-click").click(function(){
                var value = $("#inputfeld").val();

        $(".einzeln").css("display","none");

        if($(this).is(':contains(Anne)')){
            console.log(this);
            console.log("JO")
            $(this).css("display","block");


        }
});

});




    
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>I am just a text</h1>
<form>
    <input id="inputfeld" stype="text" name="">
    <button id="btn-click" type="button">Click me </button>
</form>

<div id="mutter">
    <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
<div class="alle sec_a">
    <span class="einzeln"> Anne </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Amad </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Albert  </span>

</div>
    <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
<div class="alle sec_b">
    <span class="einzeln"> Beat </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Boris </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Benny </span>

</div>
    <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
<div class="alle sec_c">
    <span class="einzeln"> China </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Cees </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Casa </span>

</div>


</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Please help. I am trying to find a solution for this problems more than 5 h :-(
my head is burning .

Answer (score 0):

In your code `$(this).is(':contains(Anne)')` is checking the text of the button, not the content elements

Following is approach using `filter()` in chain with hide/show

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-click").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()// prvent form submit
    // hide all and filter the one you want to show
    $(".einzeln").hide().filter(':contains(Anne)').show();

   
  });
});
```

```css
.d_show {
  display: "";
}

.d_none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>I am just a text</h1>
<form>
  <input id="inputfeld" stype="text" name="">
  <button id="btn-click" type="button">Click me </button>
</form>

<div id="mutter">
  <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
  <div class="alle sec_a">
    <span class="einzeln"> Anne </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Amad </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Albert  </span>

  </div>
  <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
  <div class="alle sec_b">
    <span class="einzeln"> Beat </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Boris </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Benny </span>

  </div>
  <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
  <div class="alle sec_c">
    <span class="einzeln"> China </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Cees </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Casa </span>

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Hey @charlietfl - you are great!!! Thanks a ot it works! I was so frustrated.. 

You say "In your code $(this).is(':contains(Anne)') is checking the text of the button, not the content elements" 

how could you find that out? How can I check that its the text of the button and not the element? Because of the `this`?  

And let's assume I would like to check the input - would it be this way: 

In your code `$("#inputfeld").val().is(':contains(Anne)')`
?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

**If your search is based only on "Anne" word:**

```js
var toCheck = "Anne";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-click").click(function(event) {
    if($('#inputfeld').val().trim() === toCheck){
      $(".einzeln").hide().filter(':contains(' + toCheck + ')').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>I am just a text</h1>
<form>
  <input id="inputfeld" stype="text" name="">
  <button id="btn-click" type="button">Click me </button>
</form>

<div id="mutter">
  <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
  <div class="alle sec_a">
    <span class="einzeln"> Anne </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Amad </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Albert  </span>

  </div>
  <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
  <div class="alle sec_b">
    <span class="einzeln"> Beat </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Boris </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Benny </span>

  </div>
  <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
  <div class="alle sec_c">
    <span class="einzeln"> China </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Cees </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Casa </span>

  </div>


</div>
```

---

**In case you're implementing for search box :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-click").click(function(event) {
    var toCheck = $('#inputfeld').val().trim();
    $(".einzeln").hide().filter(':contains(' + toCheck + ')').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>I am just a text</h1>
<form>
  <input id="inputfeld" stype="text" name="">
  <button id="btn-click" type="button">Click me </button>
</form>

<div id="mutter">
  <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
  <div class="alle sec_a">
    <span class="einzeln"> Anne </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Amad </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Albert  </span>

  </div>
  <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
  <div class="alle sec_b">
    <span class="einzeln"> Beat </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Boris </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Benny </span>

  </div>
  <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
  <div class="alle sec_c">
    <span class="einzeln"> China </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Cees </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Casa </span>

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your fast reply! But when I search for "Anne" , also "Amad" and "Albert" are shown. Why? Shouldn't they actually be none-displayed?

Comment: @newbie1 You mentioned entire row.. That's why I did that. Updated now.